# Windows Messaging - Various ways to get a Device Context with the non client area

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This question is for all the Windows experts.

I am doing some research on the different ways where it is possible to get a Device Context(DC) that includes the non client area of a window (using Windows API)

I know of 2 ways:

1. [GetWindowDC()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144947(v=vs.85).aspx) - returns a DC for the entire window including the non client area.
2. [GetDCEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144873(v=vs.85).aspx) - if you pass a flag of `DCX_WINDOW` you'll get a DC with the non-client area.

Are there any another ways to get a DC with the non client area?

Comment: Is there any particular reason these two options are insufficient? I'm not familiar with any other option.

Comment: why the C# and VB6 tags?  2 very different languages

Comment: @andlabs - i use hooking for my app and i need to catch all incidents where a non client area is being retrieved.

Comment: Are you merely trying to draw in the non-client area? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: i catching allot of traffic and i need it to decide what to do with other messages i catch

Comment: I am afraid this might be a loosing battle... Did you consider CS_CLASSDC, CS_OWNDC, CS_PARENTDC class styles? Also, the handle to DC  is returned in the PAINTSTRUCT when calling BeginPaint(). Also, one can use low-level API to go through process' GDI table to find it. In short - I doubt one can enumerate EVERY way to get HDC.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: The DC returned from `BeginPaint` is clipped to the client area. It cannot be used to render the non-client area. Unless the application uses DWM magic. Or mimics the non-client area inside its client area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this more complicated than it is. There really is only a single way to obtain a device context to render the non-client area of a window: [GetDCEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144873.aspx).

The rationale is simple: If you are rendering the non-client area of a window, you will be doing it from your [WM_NCPAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212.aspx) handler. This message comes with an update region (that may not be rectangular), and only `GetDCEx` can set up a non-rectangular clipping region for you.

---

Of course you could achieve the same, by manually calling [SelectClipRgn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162955.aspx) on the device context returned from [GetWindowDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144947.aspx). But that's like implementing multiplication by repeatedly adding a value in a loop, instead of using the multiplication operator.

---

Since you are trying to hook applications that are outside your control, you may also need to look for calls to [GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871.aspx) and [CreateDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490.aspx). Either one can return a DC for the entire screen (which includes the visible non-client area of windows).

Comment: your answer is good but its not relevant for me. i dont need to get a dc by calling a function, but to catch, using a hook, when a dc with non client area is being retrieved. i am catching the 2 prev mentioned ways but my testing suggest i'm missing something

Comment: Tnx, i guess your right. i was hoping i could avoid this since it adds lots of complexity (tracking the SelectObject() calls etc...) but the more i look into it the more is seems unavoidable

Answer (score 0):

These are two ways doing exactly the same thing - I don't think Microsoft would add a third function to do this.
However, getting the DC of the desktop window and drawing only to the part where your window currently is could also work. (but I don't recommand it!)

Do you try to achieve something?